# How to say that the draft is short of details?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I have made a draft specifications about some materials. But it is not fully complete. still more information needs to be provided. in the email, how to say this?

I wrote it like "Still draft is short of details." is it grammatically correct and conveys the meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing an email, it would be best to write something like, "This draft is still a work in progress; some additional details will need to be [fleshed out](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/flesh+out) before it can be < *insert what you intend to do with it after that: be sent to a client, presented to the boss, etc.* >."

Comment: Thank you. could please comment on my sentence?

Comment: It should say "The draft {the definite article "the" is needed, because we khow which draft we are talking about} is still [short **on** details](https://www.nationaljournal.com/s/659397/trumps-health-care-vision-still-short-details)." But from a practical point of view I would advise you not to draw attention to the drawbacks of what you are sending. You are denigrating your work.